# Meaning of "ça me fout la niaque"

Tags: sens, registre-familier

Dans un émail récent, mon ami a écrit "*ça m'fout la niaque*", et honnêtement je n'ai aucune idée du sens de la phrase.

Je connais les constructions suivantes:

> *se foutre de qqc/qqn* --> To not care about something/someone, or to laugh at/make fun of X
>
> *s'en foutre* --> To not care (about [implicit thing])

Mais je n'ai jamais vu la construction:

> *foutre + direct object*

Selon [Reverso](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-definition/niaque), *niaque* veut dire: *énergie vitale, volonté de réussir, "pêche", combativité*, cela ne m'aide pas à comprendre le sens de la phrase.

Mon émail original était long, et mon ami veut que sa réponse soit courte pour l'instant, mais il me rassure que l'on a beaucoup à discuter - ensuite, il a écrit cette phrase.

Quel est le sens de "*ça me fout la niaque*"?

---

In a recent email I received, my friend wrote "*ça m'fout la niaque*", and I honestly can't figure out what it means.

I know the following constructions:

> *se foutre de qqc/qqn* --> To not care about something/someone, or to laugh at/make fun of X
>
> *s'en foutre* --> To not care (about [implicit thing])

But I've never seen the construction:

> *foutre + direct object*

According to [Reverso](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-definition/niaque), *niaque* means: *énergie vitale, volonté de réussir, "pêche", combativité*, but that's not helping me to understand the meaning of the phrase.

My original email was long, and my friend wants to keep his response short for the moment, but reassures me that we have a lot to share - then, he wrote this phrase.

What is the meaning of "*ça me fout la niaque*"?

Comment: Pour reformuler un peu l'expression initiale (voilà, ok, scoop, l'ami c'était moi ^^ ) je voulais en effet dire : *Ca me donne du courage, de la motivation, un appétit de bâtisseur.*. J'approuve donc les réponses de PERCE-NEIGE et Amphiteóth.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Synonyme = ça me donne la pêche.

La niaque veut souvent dire l'envie d'y arriver, la rage (dans le bon sens).
Ensuite, tout dépend du contexte dans lequel ton ami a dit ça.

Exemple:
Je sais que ceux qui réussiront cet examen très difficile auront un salaire vraiment très élevé: ça me fout la niaque. (une grande motivation pour y arriver)

Rien à voir avec "se foutre de quelqu'un" ou 's'en foutre".
Ici: ça me fout = ça me donne.
Il n'y a pas de connotation péjorative, c'est juste une expression formulée familièrement.

Comment: Ah, intéressant, je n'ai jamais entendu 'foutre' dans un bon sens. Merci de votre réponse!

Comment: @Chris Si tu veux un autre exemple du (*très* polysémique) "foutre" avec des connotations positives, il y a l'expression (populaire) « Il/elle est bien foutu(e) », qu'on pourrait traduire *(s)he's looking good/sexy*.

Comment: Oui, dans ce cas, foutue = faite, c'est donc à peu près toujours un synonyme quelques fois un peu grossier ou en tout cas très familier du verbe "faire". Mais il est vrai qu'il a souvent une connotation péjorative, mais il peut aussi simplement remplacer le verbe faire. L'infinitif est foutre, et il est encore plus "familier".

Answer (score 6):

En complément de [la réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14148), voir au dictionnaire les constructions. Pour [*foutre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/foutre), on trouve (extraits) :

> E.− Vulg. [Avec un compl. datif]
>   1. Donner. Je t'en fous mon billet*.
>   2. [Le compl. désigne une action nuisible ou désagréable pour qqn] Donner. Foutre un coup de poing à qqn.
>   **3**. [Le compl. désigne un état psychol. ou phys., une situation] Mettre (quelqu'un) dans tel ou tel état. Ça me fout la trouille, le trac.
>   *Synon*. donner, flanquer, fiche/ficher (fam.).
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé*, TLFi - foutre ]

On note qu'il s'agit de constructions vulgaires avec complément d'objet direct; ici ce complément est [*niaque*](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/niaque/10909998?q=niaque#802031) :

> **niaque**
>  ou
>  **gnaque**
>  nom féminin
>  (du gascon gnaca,
>   mordre)
>
> Familier. Combativité, mordant.
>
> Familier. *Avoir la niaque*, avoir la volonté de vaincre.
>
> [ *Dictionnaires de français Larousse en ligne* - niaque ]

Il s'agit de la nouvelle graphie pour *gnac* (n. m., 1990, emprunt à l'occitan languedocien, passé dans le français régional, puis répandu avec le sport, surtout le rugby - *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, dir. A. Rey, ed. *Le Robert*). Donc quelque chose (ça), qui met quelqu'un (moi, me) dans un état de combativité. Qui donne du [*mordant*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mordant).